# How to make dynamic domain for Odoo 10 field (that would be given before form loads)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

What I have is two fields on them is customer and the other is customer contact:

```
   customer = fields.Many2one(res.partner)
   customer_contact = fields.Many2one(res.partner)
```

## What I made so far is:

```
    @api.onchange('customer')
    def _getCustomerContacts(self):
    res = {}
    self.customer_contact = False
    if self.customer:
         res['domain'] = {
            'customer_contact': [('id', 'in', 
    self.carrier.child_ids.ids),('type', '=', 'driver')]}
    else:
        res['domain'] = {'customer_contact': [('id', 'in', [])]}
    return res
```

This is bad solution for one reason: If i come later to form and try to change only contact, he wont have a domain, and all res partner will be displayed. I searched for answer for a while now and seems like everybody is fine with onchange solution. For me is not fine. So Maybe there would be a nice guy who had similar problem and found solution or maybe you have some suggestion what should I look for.

Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: Any solution ? i'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
@api.onchange('customer')
def _getCustomerContacts(self):
if self.customer:
    ids = []
    for child_id in self.carrier.child_ids:
        ids.append(child_id.id)

    domain = {
        'customer_contact': [('id', 'in', ids),('type', '=', 'driver')]}
else:
    domain = {'customer_contact': [('id', 'in', [])]}
return domain
```